# @Autowired does not work for class that are implementing from non-spring jpos library

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpos

I am using jpos Q2 Server with transaction manager from my spring boot application, however when i try to implement DI in my class which is implementing from the Jpos TransactionParticipant interface it is giving me the null pointer exception.

I have tried all the option that may be there in spring boot for IoC as per my understanding. It seems that TransactionParticipant third party library i am not able to register it in Spring IoC/DI module.

```
package com.fonepay.iso;

@Service("processIsoTxn")
public class ProcessIsoTxn implements TransactionParticipant{
@Autowired
    private CbsTxnService cbsTxnService;

    @Override
    public int prepare(long id, Serializable context) {
        Context ctx = (Context) context;
        try{

            ISOMsg request = (ISOMsg) ctx.get("REQUEST");

            //Call local processing Message
            //CbsTxnService cbsTxnService = new CbsTxnServiceImpl();
            ISOMsg response = cbsTxnService.createFinancialTxn(request);

            ctx.put("RESPONSE", response);
            return PREPARED;

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Process Iso Txn | error | "+ex);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
package com.fonepay.service.impl;

@Service("cbsTxnService")
@Transactional
public class CbsTxnServiceImpl implements CbsTxnService{
     public ISOMsg createFinancialTxn(ISOMsg isoMsg) {...}
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.fonepay")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class JposserverApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JposserverApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am constantly getting java.lang.NullPointerException in line 
ISOMsg response = cbsTxnService.createFinancialTxn(request);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, this is how i achieved the workaround, please refer : https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Super+simple+approach+to+accessing+Spring+beans+from+non-Spring+managed+classes+and+POJOs

```
private CbsTxnService getCbsTxnService() {
        return SpringContext.getBean(CbsTxnService.class);
    }

ISOMsg response = getCbsTxnService().createFinancialTxn(request);
```

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    /**
     * Returns the Spring managed bean instance of the given class type if it exists.
     * Returns null otherwise.
     * @param beanClass
     * @return
     */
    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {

        // store ApplicationContext reference to access required beans later on
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Try this one , replace @Autowired annotation
- Try to use constructor

```
@Service("processIsoTxn")
public class ProcessIsoTxn implements TransactionParticipant{

 private CbsTxnService cbsTxnService;

  public ProcessIsoTxn (CbsTxnService cbsTxnService) {
    this.cbsTxnService = cbsTxnService;
  }
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such constructor
 ... 31 more
      </nested-exception>
      org.jpos.core.ConfigurationException: com.fonepay.iso.ProcessIsoTxn (javax.management.ReflectionException)
 at org.jpos.q2.QFactory.newInstance(QFactory.java:323)
 at org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager.createParticipant(TransactionManager.java:766)
 at org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager.initGroup(TransactionManager.java:757)
 at org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager.initParticipants(TransactionManager.java:739)